# MongoDb. Counting fields in array

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection. Every element contains an array `topics`. Every topic contains an array `units`. Every unit contains an array `questions` and every question contains an array `ids`. How can I get count of all ids in all questions in al...in all topics? And how can I get distinct count of all ids in all...in all topics?

Comment: use an aggregation and $size https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

Comment: Could you post sample collection

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform multiple `$unwind` operation, then finally use `$size` function to get the count of ids.

```
db.your_collection.aggregate(  
    {
        $unwind:"$topics"
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$units"
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$questions"
    },
    {
       $project: {        
            numberOfItems: { $size: "$topics.units.questions.ids" }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain in my own way

that's how it's embedded https://ibb.co/ck35a0

If you want to find the elements in my document, you can filter Id not idle.

```
var line=db.getCollection('LineDefinitions').find({LineDefinitionGrid:{$exists:true}});
var lineCount=0;

line.forEach(function(item){

    lineCount+=item.LineDefinitionGrid.length;


    })
    lineCount;
```

https://ibb.co/fUHnoL